# Gcloud/GCP : Project exists but I get an Error 404 The resource project/<project_id> was not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add service projects to a gcp shared vpc, but I get an error after performing

```
gcloud --impersonate-service-account=network-admin@redacted-project-1-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com compute shared-vpc associated-projects add --host-project=main-shared-vpc-host-redacted-id redacted-project-1-id
```

The output is :

```
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [network-admin@redacted-project-1-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
WARNING: This command is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [network-admin@redacted-project-1-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.shared-vpc.associated-projects.add) Could not enable resource [redacted-project-1-id] as an associated resource for project [main-shared-vpc-host-redacted-id]:
 - The resource 'projects/redacted-project-1-id' was not found
```

NB :

1. Notice the `=network-admin@redacted-project-1-id...` exists within `redacted-project-1-id`, so the project exists. I just cannot add it as a service project to the shared vpc. An explanation and solution would be much appreciated.
2. I've successfully added other instances as service projects to this vpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do this from the console, and the error message was much clearer.

```
Projects need to have Compute Engine API enabled to be configured as service projects. Following projects can not be attached.
```

So I enabled the `compute.googleapis.com` within this project, and retried

```
gcloud --impersonate-service-account=network-admin@redacted-project-1-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com compute shared-vpc associated-projects add --host-project=main-shared-vpc-host-redacted-id redacted-project-1-id
```

It worked. `gcloud` shouldn't return `404`, but the same error as the console instead.